# Does anyone know the name of the book concerning math?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, control-theory

I want to find a book, and I have the picture of the table of contents.Does anyone know the name of the book? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be an anthology of papers. That may make identifying the book harder than reading the papers directly. Most if not all will be available via Google Scholar, especially if you use Scihub to bypass paywalls.

Comment: @J.G. I tried to search some papers on Google Scholar, but the advantage of the book is that it translates the papers into English, but on Google Scholar the papers are written in Russian.

Comment: I concur with @Fred's inference of which book it was. I just searched two chapter titles, in quotation marks to form a two-quotation search string, on Google Books; it was the top result. I hope that strategy helps you find other books in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5311923

Control Theory: Twenty-Five Seminal Papers (1932-1981)

Author :Tamer Basar

Publisher: Wiley-IEEE Press

Pages: 532

Copyright Year: 2001

Online ISBN: 9780470544334

DOI: 10.1109/9780470544334.ch4

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I want.