# Ultraproducts explicit example

Tags: model-theory

so I'm studying for my exam in the Model Theory course I take.

I just can't really wrap my head around ultraproducts. It's so abstract and complex. Is there a place where I can be shown with an explicit example of an ultraproduct, or anything close to any explicit example?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: It’s impossible to give an explicit example of a free ultrafilter, so it’s also impossible to give a completley explicit example of a non-trivial ultraproduct.

Comment: So maybe an online resource explaining it a bit more thoroughly? I can't understand the building of the structure from the ultraproduct... Or is the only solution reading it over and over until I get it?

Comment: The second PDF linked from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/315773/12042) goes into the specific example of constructing the hyperreals as an ultrapower of $\Bbb R$ in quite a bit of detail; you might find it helpful.

Comment: You’re welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think if it in terms of finitely additive measures.  A non-principal filter on $\{ 0,1,2,3,\ldots \}$ contains every cofinite set, so think of a measure that behaves like this
$$
m(A) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $A$ is finite}, \\ 1 & \text{if the complement of $A$ is finite}, \\  \text{???} & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Zorn's lemma implies the domain of this measure can be extended to the whole set of all subsets of $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, so you have a function $m$ assigning $0$ or $1$ to every subset, and the measure of a set is $1$ iff the measure of its complement is $0$, and this measure is finitely additive, i.e. $m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B)$ if $A\cap B=\varnothing$.  The ultrafilter is the set of all sets of measure $1$.

A first-order sentence is true in an ultraproduct if and only if it is true in **almost every** factor, and that means the measure of the set of factors in which is is not true is $0$.  That statement is a theorem rather than a definition, called Łoś's theorem.  ("Ł" is pronounced like the "W" in "Washington", and "ś" like "sh" in "Washington".  It's a Polish name.)

So you have an indexed family of structures $B_i,\  i\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ (or the index set could be some other set).  A member of the product $\prod_{i=0}^\infty B_i$ is a sequence $b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots$, or if the index set is something other than $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, then an indexed family $(b_i)_{i\in\text{index set}}$.  Each structure $B_i$ has not only an underlying set but also some "structure", which can be some relations or functions on $B_i$. Let's set you have a binary relation $R_i$ among members of $B_i$.  You then have a product relation $R$ according to which $x$ is related to $y$, i.e. $x\,R\,y$, if and only if for every index $i$ you have $x_i\,R_i\,y_i$.

In the **ultraproduct** rather than the product, you have $x\,R\,y$ if and only if for **almost** every index $i$ you have $x_i\,R_i\,y_i$ (with "almost" defined as above).

If $F$ is the ultrafilter --- the set of subsets of the index set whose complements have measure $0$ --- then the ultraproduct is denoted $\prod_{i=0}^\infty B_i/F$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you  very much.

Comment: @Reyo : Glad you liked it.